# Does a cache write take longer with more caches to invalidate?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, cpu-cache

can you please help me to find out if it takes longer for a cache write to finish when there are more cores/caches holding a copy of that line.
I also want to measure/quantify how much longer it actually takes.

I couldn't find anything useful on google and I have trouble measuring it myself plus interpret what I measure because of the many things that can happen on a modern processor.
(reordering, prefetching, buffering and god knows what)

**Details:**

My basic process of measuring it is roughly as follows:

```
write soemthing to the cacheline on processor 0
read it on processors 1 to n.

rdtsc
write it on process 0
rdtsc
```

I am not even sure which instructions to actually use for read/write on process 0 in order to make sure the write/invalidate is finished before the final time measurement.

At the moment I fiddle with an atomic exchange (__sync_fetch_and_add()), but it seems that the number of threads is itself important for the length of this operation (not the number of threads to invalidate) -- which is probably not what I want to measure?!.

I also tried a read, then write, then memory barrier (__sync_synchronize()). This looks more like what I expect to see,
but here I am also not sure if the write is finished when the final rdtsc takes place.

As you can guess my knowledge of CPU internals is somewhat limited.

Any help is very much appreciated!

ps:
 * I use linux, gcc and pthreads for the measurements.
 * I want know this for modeling a parallel algorithm of mine.

**Edit:**

In a week or so (going on vacation tomorrow) I'll do some more research and post my code and notes and link it here (In case someone is interested), because the time I can spend on this is limited.

Comment: If your version of gcc is recent enough, you may want to use the much improved [__atomic](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) builtins. You may also want to read up on the [MESI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI) cache coherance protocol. It's not the only protocol but it'll give you a better idea on how atomic operations are implemented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started writing a very long answer, describing exactly how this works, then realized, I probably don't know enough about the exact details. So I'll do a shorter answer....

So, when you write something on one processor, if it's not already in that processors cache, it will have to be fetched in, and after the processor has read the data, it will perform the actual write. In doing so, it will send a cache-invalidate message to ALL other processors in the system. These will then throw away any content. If another processor has "dirty" content, it will in itself write out the data, and ask for an invalidation - in which case the first processor will have to RELOAD the data before finishing its write (otherwise, some other element in the same cacheline may get destroyed).

Reading it back into the cache will be required on every other processor that is interested in that cache-line.

The __sync_fetch_and_add() wilol use a "lock" prefix [on x86, other processors may vary, but the general idea on processors that support "per instruction" locks is roughtly the same] - this will issue a "I want this cacheline EXCLUSIVELY, everyone else please give it up and invalidate it". Just like the first case, the processor may well have to re-read anything that another processor may have made dirty.

A memory barrier will not ensure that data is updated "safely" - it will just make sure that "whatever happened (to memory) before now is visible to all processors by the time this instructon finishes".

The best way to optimize the use of processors is to share as little as possible, and in particular, avoid "false sharing". In a benchmark many years ago, there was a structure like [simplifed] this:

```
struct stuff {
    int x[2];
    ... other data ... total data a few cachelines. 
} data;

void thread1()
{
    for( ... big number ...)
        data.x[0]++;
}

void thread2()
{
    for( ... big number ...)
        data.x[1]++;
}

int main()
{
    start = timenow();

    create(thread1);
    create(thread2);

    end = timenow() - start;   
}
```

Since EVERY time thread1 wrote to the x[0], thread2's processor had to get rid of it's copy of x[1], and vice versa, the result is was that the SMP test [vs just running thread1] was running about 15 times slower. By altering the struct like this:

```
struct stuff {
    int x;
    ... other data ... 
} data[2];
```

and

```
void thread1()
{
    for( ... big number ...)
        data[0].x++;
}
```

we got 200% of the 1 thread variant [give or take a few percent]

Right, so the processor has queues of buffers where write operations are stored when the processor is writing to memory. A memory barrier (mfence, sfence or lfence) instruction is there to ensure that any outstanding read/write, write or read type operation has completely been finished before the processor proceeds to the next instruction. Normally, the processor would just continue on it's jolly way through any following instructions, and eventualy the memory operation becomes fulfilled some way or another. Since modern processors have a lot of parallel operations and buffers all over the place, it can take quite some time before something ACTUALLY trickles through to where it eventually will end up. So, when it's CRITICAL to make sure that something has ACTUALLY been done before proceeding (for example, if we have written a bunch of instructions to the video memory, and we now want to kick off the run of those instructions, we need to make sure that the 'instruction' writing has actually finished, and some other part of the processor isn't still working on finishing that. So use an `sfence` to make sure that the write has really happened - that may not be a very realistic example, but I think you get the idea.)

Comment: So the atomic exchange would be the right operation for measurement? In my measurement it seems that regardless of the number of cores to be invalidated, the total number of threads is important for this (the number of idling threads spawned in the program -- which is weird, is it not?).

Comment: You haven't really posted that much detail about what you expect, and how the numbers differen from what you expect. Do you see much difference if you don't use the locked (__sync...) operations?

Comment: If I do a read, write, memory barrier (__sync_synchronize) it does not increase with increasing idle thread count, but it increases with to be invalidated core count (which is what I expect --- But i am not sure if this is what I want to measure? Is it? I dont know.). If do just read, write it gets magicked away and i get only the rdtsc cycles themselves ~20-40, no differences whatsoever. I will spend a couple more hours (in a week or so) on this, but since this is not a super important question my time is limited. But I can post my stuff and notes at the end if you like.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that sync_synchronise simply holds up the processor until the write buffers have been cleared - which will probably take some time. By all means, post some more info!

Comment: I will in a week when I'm back from vacation. I hoped you could answer it in general. I'm not even sure what it means "the write buffers have been cleared". I want it to make sure the cachewrite happened, and all other caches have been invalidated ... with which instructions can I make sure of this?

Comment: I've done it again: My comment was too big, so I had to add it at the end of the answer...

Answer (score 4):

Cache writes have to get line-ownership before dirtying the cache line. Depending on the
cache coherence model implemented in the processor architecture, the time taken for this step varies. The most common coherence protocols that I know are:

- Snooping Coherence Protocol: all caches monitor address lines for cached memory lines i.e. all memory requests have to be broadcast to all cpus i.e. non-scalable as cpus increase.
- Directory-based Coherence Protocol: all cache lines shared among many cpus is kept in a directory; so, invalidating/gaining ownership is a point-to-point cpu request rather than a broadcast i.e. more scalable, but latency suffers because the directory is a single point of contention.

Most cpu architectures support something called PMU (perf monitoring unit). This unit exports
counters for many things like: cache hits, misses, cache write latency, read latency, tlb hits, etc. Please consult the cpu manual to see if this info is available.

Comment: So what is done in modern x86 processors? And does it take longer on more cores? And how can I measure it?